# Algorithm to optimally distribute multiple writer threads on multiple physical disks

Tags: multithreading, algorithm

I have a logical store which has multiple physical disks assigned to it

STORE

- X:\
- Y:\
- Z:\
- ...

I also have a pool of threads that write data (size unknown) to the STORE. Is there an algorithm which I can use (load balancing, scheduling... etc.) to help me determine on which physical disk I should write?

Factors to take under consideration:

1. Free disk space available.
2. Disk utilization (proper distribution of threads across physical disks).
3. Free space % on all disks should be more or less be the same.

Notes:

- Each thread has its own data to process, so a single thread can sleep if its data is not available.
- Disks are not necessarily the same size.
- One or more disks could be taken offline.
- One or more disks could be added to the STORE.

UPDATE:
I should've explained the objective of these threads better in my question; these threads read from different data sources/streams and write immediately to disk(s), buffering steams in memory is not much of an option because their size tend to grow huge quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you go with is going to require some tuning. What I describe below is a simple and effective starting point that might very well fit your needs.

First, I doubt that you actually need three threads to handle writing to three disk drives. The amount of processing required to orchestrate this is actually quite small.

As a first cut, you could do a simple round-robin scheduling with one thread and asynchronous writes. That is, you just have a circular queue that you fill with `[X, Y, Z]`. When a request comes in, you take a disk from the front of the queue and initiate an asynchronous write to that drive.

When the next request comes in, you again take the first item from the queue and issue an asynchronous write.

When an asynchronous write completes, the disk to which the data was written is added to the end of the queue.

If a drive is taken offline, it's removed from the queue. If a drive is added to the store, you make a new entry for it in the queue.

An obvious problem with the above is what to do if you get more concurrent write requests than you have drives. Using the technique I described above, the thread would have to block until there is a drive available. If you have to support bursts of activity, you could easily create a request queue into which requests are written (with their associated data). The thread doing the orchestration, then, would read an item from the queue, get a disk drive from the drive queue, and start the asynchronous write.

Note that with this setup, no drive can be doing more than a single write at a time. That's typically not a problem because the drive hardware typically can't handle multiple concurrent writes.

Keeping free space percentage relatively the same across drives might not be much harder. You could keep track of the free space percentage on each drive easily enough, and rather than using a FIFO queue for the drives, use a priority queue so that you always write to the drive that has the highest free space percentage. That will work well as long as your average write size isn't a huge percentage of a drive's free space.

### Edit

Note that I said *asynchronous writes*. So you can have as many concurrent writes as you have drives. Those writes are running concurrently and will notify on an I/O completion port when done. There's no need for multiple threads.

As for the priority queue, there are plenty of those to choose from, although finding a good concurrent priority queue is a bit more work. In the past I've just used locks to synchronize access to [my own priority queue implementation](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/12/18/posting-the-heap-code/). I guess I should formalize that at some point.

You could play with what I describe above by, for example, adding two or more entries in the queue for each drive. More for faster drives, fewer for slower drives. It's unclear how well that would work, but it's probably worth trying. If those "drives" are high performance network storage devices, they might actually be able to handle multiple concurrent writes better than a typical local disk drive can. But at some point you'll have to buffer writes because your computer can almost certainly create data much faster than your drives can write. The key is making your buffer large enough to handle the normal bursts of data, and also robust enough to block the program briefly if the buffer fills up.